# Visual Studio Local db Stores Non-English Characters as '?' Question Mark

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am using a local data base in visual studio 2013 to create a windows form application.I want to insert non-English characters into my local db in visual studio. my database fields are as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sgn] (
    [IdSgn]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [Sgn]      NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [SgnTitle] NVARCHAR (250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CI_AS NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IdSgn] ASC)
);
```

when i run this query :

```
Insert into sgn values (( select isnull(max(idsgn),0)+1 from sgn  ) , 'بهنام' , 'بهنام'  )
```

the result is:

```
1  | ????? | ?????
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert the strings using Unicode literals (prefixed with `N`):

```
Insert into sgn values (( select isnull(max(idsgn),0)+1 from sgn  ) , N'بهنام' , N'بهنام'  )
```